# Python switch the output based on input

Tags: python, function

Can we write the following code in one line, when a function switch the current player another one?

```
    def switch_user(self,current):
       if self.current == 'Player-1':
              self.current = 'Player-2'
      elif self.current == 'Player-2':
           self.current = 'Player-1'
    return
```

Comment: See [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: @e0k While that would work, it sounds like this question isn't really asking about equivalents for a `switch` statement - the use of the word "switch" is coincidental. It seems to be asking how to concisely toggle between two values.

Comment: @DavidZ Good point. The code looks similar to a switch statement because it is making multiple comparisons against the same value. That must have distracted me. The word "switch" in the question only refers to switching players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.current = 'Player-2' if self.current == 'Player-1' else 'Player-1'
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `current == 'Player-1'` instead of `self.current == 'Player-1'`?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi `current` would make more sense (otherwise you're not using the argument), but then the example in the question is also incorrect.

Comment: I am using self because 'current' is a global variable, with self.current it becomes local.

Answer (score 1):

To make things expandable to multiple players I'd use `cycle` from the itertools standard library https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

```
from itertools import cycle      

players_cycle = cycle(['Player-1', 'Player-2'])

current = players_cycle()
```

This way you are able add a third player or make the player objects more complex over time Without having to redo the switch function.